# How can I send scheduled emails with specific data without having to render it inside a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-schedule

So I started working at this company a few months ago, and I have been asked to send scheduled emails every other day about machines that have had recurring issues within a certain time frame.  The dev before me created a script to be able to do this but there is a bit of a problem with how he decided to implement it.  The way it was being implemented was that he decided to create a component for these scheduled emails using node-shceduler, and this component was being rendered within the main components render method, which to me was a big red flag.  The problem is that whenever this main component is rendered, the scheduled script gets ran as well, and with all the times setState is called in the main component the script component gets rendered and bogs down the system.

I realize that this is very inefficient, and I feel like it could be done a better way.  My main idea was to put this schedule method server side, but the issue is that I'm not sure how I would be able to get my data from the db to the server to do this.

Here is my Timedscripts.js file

```js
export default class Timedscripts extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
        };
    }

   TimedScript(email){
let logs = this.props.logs;
        let temp = [];

        for(let j = 0; j < logs.length; j++){
            if(logs[j].KioskID != 'Testing'){
                temp.push(logs[j].KioskID)
            }
        }

        let uniq = [... new Set(temp)];

        let hash = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < uniq.length; i++){
            let count = 0;
            for(let j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){
              if(temp[j] == uniq[i]){
                count = count + 1;
                }
            }
          hash.push(count);
        }

       let results = [];

       for(let k = 0; k < hash.length; k++){
           if(hash[k] >= 2){
               results.push(uniq[k]);
           }
       }


        if(this.state.count3 == 0){
            var r = schedule.scheduleJob('0 19 * * *', function(){  // schedule for 7pm everyday
                if(results.length != 0){
                    var arrayToEmail = [];
                    for(var l = 0; l < results.length; l++){
                        arrayToEmail.push(results[l] + '\n')
                    }

                    var to = email;

                    var text =
                                `<div width="100%",style="text-align:left;">` +
                                `<h1 style="text-align:center;">Machines With Reccuring Issues</h1>` +
                                `<table border="1", width="100%">` +
                                `<tbody style="text-align:left;">` +
                                `<tr><td width="300">Machine(s) that have had 2 or more issues within the last 30 days.</td></tr>` +
                                arrayToEmail + 
                                `</tbody>` +
                                `</table >` +
                                `</div >`;

                        console.log("Sending Email")
                        $.get("/send", { to: to, subject: 'Machines to Watch', text: text }, function (data) { });
                }
            })
            this.setState({count: 1})
            }
   }

   render(){
     return(
<div>
                <button id="30Days" onClick={() => this.TimedScript(this.props.msgList.EmailTo)} style={{display: 'none'}}></button>

            </div>
     );
   }
}
```

I've found that the count is used to stop this module from creating as many emails as many times as the main component renders, which again seems really bad imo.  The '/send' sends an email from the server side.

Here is the main component

```js
export default class MainComponent extends React.Component{
... some methods and such

render(){
 return(
  <div>
    ...some html
 <TimedScripts logs={this.state.LogHistory} inventoryItems={this.props.inventoryItems} alerts={this.props.alerts} issues={this.props.issues} info={this.props.kiosksInfo} starPaper={this.props.starPaper} msgList={this.props.msgList} completedJobs={this.props.completedJobs}/> 

 script{
   setTimeout(function(){                 
     $('#30Days').trigger('click') 
   }, 5000)
 }   
  </div>
 );

}


}
```

As you can see, every time the main component gets rendered this script component will mount and run it's methods over and over.

I get the info I need from calling sockets in the main component which then call a db procedure, and this info is then passed onto the TimedScripts component.  If anyone has ideas on how I can just make that component render once, or if there is just a better more efficient way of doing this I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: If the sole purpose is to query a database and send emails, then you don’t need a front facing component. Instead separate this logic into a micro service. A simple server side node instance with node-scheduler ought to work. I can provide an example if needed.

Comment: @MattCarlotta yes I just need to query a database and then perform some methods to filter out the machines that I want, and then send this in an email.  If you could provide an example for this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, microservice should be more than sufficient. Heres a multi purpose microservice I created for a scheduling application. It’s primarily focus is to poll my database and look for Mail documents to hand off to Sendgrid (3rd party emailing service). In addition, once a month, it generates monthly schedules per user and creates a Mail (email) document per user. It also creates monthly AP forms and generates new Events according to another API: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/SJSITApp-Agent

Comment: The importance behind it is that it’s not attached to the main app, but runs alongside it. It’s not front facing and not interactive, as such, it can crash and it won’t affect the app (aside from some services being temporarily unavailable).

Comment: @MattCarlotta So I'm not very familiar with microservices in a web application.  I believe that my companies application implements microservices, but comparing your example to mine is kind of difficult to understand where I need to put mine.  I have a server.js file where the express server is created, I also have middleware which is where all my sockets are contained.  We have an app.js file where basically all my components get rendered, and also an API module where my db procedures exist.  I know it's hard to understand without actually seeing all the code.

Comment: I use `pm2` and `nginx` to serve my application. Basically, pm2 spawns 3 separate processes, while nginx runs the main application and an image microservice. Each part is independently run on its own process and therefore independent of each other (if one process crashes, the rest remain unaffected). However, their common link is that they share access to the database. In short: Process 1 => Main app (the schedule app that users interactive with), Process 2 => Agent (polling services), Process 3 => Image service.

Comment: The database (Mongo) runs in its own process and therefore is accessible to any service that needs to connect to it. That said, if you can't run multiple processes, then you can attach it (`require` the main microservice `app.js` file) where the express server is spawned and it'll run as long as the server is up.

Comment: @MattCarlotta do you have a server file in your example?

Comment: No, I don't have a `server.js` file as I'm not using express for this microservice. Instead it's just a simple node application that can connect to my database. I run this application via pm2 :https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2, which spawns a process that essentially runs `node app.js` separately from the main application. It doesn't have a port nor does it connect directly with the application. It's merely polling my database via connecting to the mongodb client: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/SJSITApp-Agent/blob/master/database/index.js#L20

Comment: I'm not sure what database you're using but most have some way to connect them -- whether it's within node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose#connecting-to-mongodb or within the shell: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/access-mongo-shell-help/

Comment: @MattCarlotta ok that makes sense, now I understand what your code is doing.  I think you have given me some good ideas on what to look at within my code.  I appreciate your help.